# Error: How to allow the “contributor” to upload media in wordpress

Tags: users, user-roles

am facing a problem with my wordpress site.In my site I prevent/disallow the "contributor" to upload media files.

But I want them to upload only the featured image. So what is the trick in that case?? Is there any code?? or any plugins?? I searched a lot but found nothing related to it. I badly need that. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I try this code :-

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
$contributor = get_role('contributor');
$contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

But when contributor start upload media, its show him an error and cannot upload images and download this file :-

```
async-upload.php
```

Comment: I don't think that will be possible. Because featured images are like any other image files uploaded to media library. The only difference is that they have a post metadata to make them featured images.

Comment: So, What can i do ??, Where is problem

Comment: If you want them to upload featured image then allow the "contributor" to upload media files.

Comment: i allowed by my code above in post, its show him but cannot uplaod

Answer (score 1):

This is what I just used, maybe there was a problem in past versions of WordPress or your theme.

```
function allow_contrib_upload() {

    // get the role
    $contrib = get_role( 'contributor' );

    // add the upload capability
    $contrib->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'allow_contrib_upload', 11 );
```